# JavaScript trigger action based on dropdown value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to modify some JavaScript that I have to make it so that when a option is selected depending on the num value it will run a different action.

Here is what my current JavaScript looks like:

```
 jQuery(".frequency_new_selector").on("change", function() {
         jQuery('.frequency_new_label option:first-child').attr("disabled", "disabled");
         jQuery(".frequency_num").val(jQuery(".frequency_new_selector").find("option[value='" + jQuery(".frequency_new_selector").val() + "']").data("num"));
         jQuery(".frequency_type").val(jQuery(".frequency_new_selector").find("option[value='" + jQuery(".frequency_new_selector").val() + "']").data("type"));
         jQuery(".frequency_type_text").attr("value", jQuery(".frequency_type option[value='" + jQuery(".frequency_type").val() + "']").text());
         if (jQuery(".frequency_new_selector").val() !== null && $(".single-option-radio input:checked").length == $(".single-option-radio").length) {
             jQuery("#AddToCart").removeAttr("disabled");
         }
      });
```

I would like to add a line in that looks like this:

```
if (jQuery(".frequency_new_selector").val() == 1 {
                 event.preventDefault();
                 $('.cd-popup').addClass('is-visible');
             }
```

My HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="frequency_new_label" style="">
    <select class="frequency_new_selector">
        <option selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Please Select Shipping Interval</option>
        <option data-type="2" data-num="1" value="1">Weekly</option>
        <option data-type="3" data-num="1" value="2">Monthly</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: *"I would like to add a line in that looks like this"* -  So what happened when you tried it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yours should work the way you have done it...  However i would probably change it slightly as you are making an unnecessary jQuery call and they are quite expensive operations.

When your change callback gets called `this` will be assigned to the DOM element (dropdown).

```js
$(".frequency_new_selector").on("change", function() {
  if (this.value === '1') {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('.cd-popup').addClass('is-visible');
  }
});
```

Comment: No worries!  Glad i could help.